# На каком слое публиковать интерфейсы?

Tags: mvvm, архитектура, проектирование, интерфейс

Я пытаюсь разделить свою систему по слоям. Получается примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай скажу, что использую паттерн MVVM. Хотя по-моему это не относится к вопросу. Вот у меня есть 4 слоя. Слой View обращается к слою ViewModel. То есть слой `View` клиент `ViewModel`. Я хочу что бы классы слоя `View` зависели не от конкретных классов `ViewModel`, а от интерфейсов. Где мне публиковать эти интерфейсы? Принцип OCP(open/closed principle) говорит, что интерфейсы принадлежат клиентам. Но если я опубликую интерфейсы для классов слоя `ViewModel` в слое `View`, получится что `ViewModel` зависит от `View`.

Comment: Окей, а почему бы не опубликовать интерфейсы VM в самой VM?

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы V зависело только от интерфейсов, сделайте интерфейсы публичными, а конкретные имплементации обозначьте как `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, если что не так говорю, но мне кажется, что:

- *View* и *ViewModel* хорошо бы были в одном слое. Все-таки *ViewModel* это скорее про логику презентации
- не стоит заменять *ViewModel* на ее интерфейс, а вместо этого лучше чтобы *ViewModel* принимала в конструктор интерфейс сервиса, работающего с данными. Во вью модели есть шелуха (у меня обычно бывает), касающаяся представления, например, флаг IsBusy (загрузка данных). Такую шелуху надо будет дублировать от интерфейса к интерфейсу, если использовать `IViewModel`, а это не обязательно.

Если не *DDD*, а попроще, то можно было бы иметь 3 слоя (как вариант).

- User Interface (v, vm)
- Application Services (управление работы с репозиториями, логика, **интерфейсы application service-ов**)
- Persistence (репозитории, работающие с БД)

Наверное, это что-то близкое к *CRUD*. Принимаю критику.

---

*disclaimer: говорю с колокольни WPF*

---

Следующая схема и все, что написано ниже **уже не относится к вопросу**. Просто, [Monk в своем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524684/185885) показал диаграмму зависимостей слоев, кажется для *DDD*. Мне захотелось привести в пример, как это у нас для *DDD* сработало. К тому же уже была готовая диаграмма (зависимостей сборок). Немного посложнее, а может быть и примерно то же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовали *IoC*. Интерфейсы находились в следующих сборках:

- в Application Service Layer - интерфейсы для сервисов
- в Domain Layer - интерфейсы доменного уровня

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, я пока ни разу не видел идеальных решений по этой теме. В DDD интерфейсы можно засунуть в доменной слой, который доступен всем снаружи:

[image: DDD Layers]

Если вдруг вам покажется, что к доменному слою оно не относится - интерфейсы явно переезжают в слой приложения, чтобы UI мог к ним обращаться.